# Dynamic Index for paged table

Tags: javascript, css, html, dynamic

I am creating a table that is paged(showing only 10 elements per page). im not sure how big the table will be since the user is adding it dynamically. I want to have numbers that correspond to the pages in the table and when the user clicks on one of the pages it loads that page's elements. i also want to show which page the user is currently on. 
currently I have a integer keeping track of the page the user is on, a next back, first and last button.
all i really need to know is how to create a dynamic set of numbers that are clickable.
I am using chrome browser, HTML5 and JS.

thanx in advance

Java script

```
       function display(){//shows the Status Table
            document.getElementById("DStatusTable").hidden='';
            document.getElementById("buttons").hidden='';
            var table = document.getElementById('statusTable');
            for(var i =1; i<table.rows.length; i++){
                var x =table.rows[i].cells;
                table.rows[i].id ='notselected';
                table.rows[i].hidden='';
                if (!((pageCUR*10+i)>fileLIST.length)){
                    x[0].innerHTML = fileLIST[pageCUR*10+(i-1)]
                                            [0].name;
                    x[1].innerHTML = fileLIST[pageCUR*10+
                                            (i-1)][1];  
                                    }
                else{   
                    table.rows[i].hidden='hidden';
                                    }


    function nextPage(){//shows next page
       pageCUR++;
       if (pageCUR>=parseInt(pageMAX)){//checks if on last page
        document.getElementById('Next').hidden='hidden';
        document.getElementById('Last').hidden='hidden'; }
       else {
        document.getElementById('Next').hidden='';
        document.getElementById('Last').hidden=''; 
               }
       document.getElementById('Back').hidden='';
       document.getElementById('First').hidden='';
       display(); 
    }

    function backPage(){//shows previous page
       pageCUR--;
       if (pageCUR==0){//checks if on first page
        document.getElementById('Back').hidden='hidden';
        document.getElementById('First').hidden='hidden';
               }        
       else{ 
        document.getElementById('Back').hidden='';
        document.getElementById('First').hidden='';
               }
       document.getElementById('Next').hidden=''    
       document.getElementById('Last').hidden=''    
       display();
     }

     function firstPage(){//shows first page
       pageCUR =0;
       document.getElementById('First').hidden='hidden';
       document.getElementById('Back').hidden='hidden';
       document.getElementById('Next').hidden='';
       document.getElementById('Last').hidden='';
       display();
     }

     function lastPage(){//shows last page
       pageCUR =parseInt(pageMAX);
       document.getElementById('First').hidden='';
       document.getElementById('Back').hidden='';
       document.getElementById('Next').hidden='hidden';
       document.getElementById('Last').hidden='hidden';
       display();
    }
```

HTML5

```
    <div class="StatusTable" id="DStatusTable" hidden>
        <table id='statusTable' border='1'>
        <thead><tr>
                <th> NAME</th>
                <th>STATUS</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr id="row1">
                <td onclick = "play(0)">video 1</td>
                <td onclick="SET(this,0)" ></td></tr>
            <tr id="row2">
                <td onclick = "play(1)">video 1</td>
                <td onclick="SET(this,1)" ></td></tr>
            <tr id="row3">
                <td onclick = "play(2)">video 1</td>
                <td onclick="SET(this,2)" ></td></tr>
            <tr id="row4">
                <td onclick = "play(3)">video 1</td>
                <td onclick="SET(this,3)" ></td></tr>
            <tr id="row5">
                <td onclick = "play(4)">video 1</td>
                <td onclick="SET(this,4)" ></td></tr>
            <tr id="row6">
                <td onclick = "play(5)">video 1</td>
                <td onclick="SET(this,5)" ></td></tr>
            <tr id="row7">
                <td onclick = "play(6)">video 1</td>
                <td onclick="SET(this,6)" ></td></tr>
            <tr id="row8">
                <td onclick = "play(7)">video 1</td>
                <td onclick="SET(this,7)" ></td></tr>
            <tr id="row9">
                <td onclick = "play(8)">video 1</td>
                <td onclick="SET(this,8)" ></td></tr>
            <tr id="row10">
                <td onclick = "play(9)">video 1</td>
                <td onclick="SET(this,9)" ></td></tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

as well as i have 2 global variables pageCUR and pageMAX which hold the index of the current  page and the index of the max(last) page

Comment: Sry this is my first post. this is based off of html5 and JS (as the tags say). i looked online trying to find it and i was only hoping that some1 could give me a general direction as to how to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is what i ended up using to change my page

JS

```
    function makePagination(){
        var x = document.getElementById('pagination');
        var y='|';
        for(var i=0; i<=(pageMAX); i++){
            y= y+"<a id ='pageNumber"+i+"' onclick='changePage("+       (i+1)+");'>"+(i+1)+"</a>\n ";
           if(i!=(fileLIST.length/10)) y=y+' | ';
        }
        x.innerHTML=y   
    }
    function changePage(k){
        pageCUR = k-1;
        display();
    }
```

along with the HTML div

```
      <div id='pagination'></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how you may generate a pagination in JavaScript (using jQuery): [JSFiddle-Example](http://jsfiddle.net/3U9sB/1/)

Please note, that `window.changePage = function ...` is just a workaround in JSFiddle to make this function global. Your JScript-Code to load the next page goes right into it.

```
function changePage (page){
 alert('change page to ' + page);   
}

function makePagination(n){
    for(var i=0; i<=5; i++){
        $("<a onclick='changePage("+i+");'>"+i+"</a>").appendTo('#pagination'); 
        if(i!=5) $('#pagination').append(' | ');
    }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    makePagination(5); // Number of pages
});
```

with

```
<div id='pagination'></div>​
```

​

Comment: "all i really need to know is how to create a dynamic set of numbers that are clickable" -> What's wrong with this answer? Please explain!

Comment: nothing is really wrong with this answer it is just that some of the syntax wasn't working for me. it lead me to what i wanted to do so thank you for that.